# Есть таблица, в которой user_id, payment_id, date. Как узнать дату первого платежа по каждому из пользователей?

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица, в которой user_id, payment_id, date. Как узнать дату первого платежа по каждому из пользователей?

Мой код SELECT * FROM payments where ( select distinct payments.user_id)   GROUP BY payment_date;

Возвращает всех пользователей, а мне нужно ід пользователя и его самый ранний платеж

Comment: select user_id, min(date) as firstpayment from payments  group by user_id

Comment: Спасибо, работает

Answer (score 1):

обычная группировка по user_id с минимальной датой

```
select user_id, min(date) as firstpayment from payments group by user_id
```